# overriding edtitext's getText() method causes stackoverflow, why?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

i am subclassing TextInputEditText so that i can add a string to a password editText field.  here is the subclass:

```
public class CustomInputEditTextWithPrefix extends TextInputEditText {


public CustomInputEditTextWithPrefix(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomInputEditTextWithPrefix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomInputEditTextWithPrefix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public Editable getText() {
    Editable s = (Editable) super.getText(); //why is this causing infinite stackoverflow ?
    if(s!=null && s.length()>0) {
      //salt the password
        Editable pwSalt = new SpannableStringBuilder("my secret string");
        s= pwSalt.append(s);
    }
     return s;
}
```

}

and the imlementation in xml is:

```
<com.myapp.ui.auth.ui.customviews.CustomInputEditTextWithPrefix
           android:id="@+id/password"
           android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

my issue is that when i execute the code the getText() override method keeps getting called over and over again. i took out the inputType  but its still being called until stackoverflow.  my idea was to append to the front of every string in the TextInputEditText a secret hash.  What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you skip to assign a new value of `s` everything will be OK

```
   @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = (Editable) super.getText();
        if(s!=null && s.length()>0) {
            //salt the password
            return new SpannableStringBuilder("my secret string").append(s.toString());
        }
        return s;
    }
```